# how fix bug with firefox different line-height with css input type button and a button bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

bug with firefox v. 27.0.1 in input type"Button" line-height is 17px but in css line-height:20px !important; look at the picture[image]

please help me

Comment: This isn't a bug, line height should have no effect on a replaced element's content. Actually if Chrome respects `line-height`s specified on `input[type=button]` then Chrome has a bug. See replaced elements ([1](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements),[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)) and [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fline-height) docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can replace the `input` by a `button` and the line height will work.

So, don't use

```html
<input type="button" value="Relate and publish" />
```

but use

```html
<button type="button">Relate and publish</button>
```

instead. See http://jsfiddle.net/XHw4L/4/

Or, if you can't change the HTML at all, you can change the height to the input explicitly to match the height of the button. In this example, `28px` would do the trick, but you may have to fiddle a bit if there are other styles defined elsewhere.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHw4L/7/).

Comment: this link generate by wiget bootstrap in yii framwork thats my problem line height ! Examples
Input type: button [source w3school] (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Comment: You mean you can't change the HTML? Your question didn't mention that; please make a note of restrictions like that in future questions. I have added a solution with only cSS changes now; how's this?